# is android:exported="true" required for internal use of content provider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have defined a provider in my application manifest :

```
<provider
    android:authorities="com.example.myapp.provider"
    android:name="com.example.myapp.MyProvider">
</provider>
```

The provider is required only to be used within the application. But I get the below error when i try to run my activity :

```
Failed to find provider info..
```

But it works perfectly if i simply set the export attribute of the provider in the manifest :

```
android:exported="true"
```

So my question is why is this required? Because, according to the documentation(http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html#exported), export is required only if the provider is to be available for other applications. Am i doing something wrong?

**[Edit] :** Suprisingly, the error has disappeared now even after removing the exported attribute, without making any other changes. I have no clue why it is working now. Probably some stupid mistake from my side. I leave this question open in hope of getting any clues as to what must have gone wrong.

**[Edit] :** I am facing this issue again with a receiver this time. So it was not a mistake from my side, as i assumed in my previous edit. I suspect something is wrong in the ADT build tool.

Comment: your authorities tag is not the same as your contentProvier (MyProvider vs provider). On doc says <i>Typically, it's the name of the ContentProvider subclass that implements the provider</i>

Comment: I did not really understand your comment. "MyProvider" is the name of my content provider class, which is in the package "com.example.myapp". And that's what i have specified for the "android:name" attribute. I named the "android:authorities"  value randomly. I don't have any class named "provider". Anyway i don't think the name is a problem since the same names work when the provider is exported.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your `<provider>` tag is inside the `<application>...</application>` tags.

```
<application>
    ...
    <provider
        android:authorities="com.ingamedeo.databasetest.contentprovider"
        android:name=".db.ContentProviderDb"
        android:exported="false">            
    </provider>
</application>
```

Comment: Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463767/failed-to-find-provider-info-for-custom-provider

Answer (score -1):

**Update:** You can no longer set

> android:exported="true"

you will encounter  `java.lang.SecurityException: Provider must not be exported` exception.