# java.lang.SecurityException: Failed to find provider KickObject for user?

Tags: java, android

I am getting crash android app while saving data using https://github.com/emilsjolander/sprinkles. its only crashing in Samsung s8.

> java.lang.SecurityException: Failed to find provider KickObject for user 0; expected to find a valid ContentProvider for this
>   authority
>                                                                            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1948)
>                                                                            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1894)
>                                                                            at
>   android.content.IContentService$Stub$Proxy.notifyChange(IContentService.java:801)
>                                                                            at
>   android.content.ContentResolver.notifyChange(ContentResolver.java:2046)
>                                                                            at
>   android.content.ContentResolver.notifyChange(ContentResolver.java:1997)
>                                                                            at
>   se.emilsjolander.sprinkles.Model$1.onTransactionCommitted(Model.java:138)
>                                                                            at se.emilsjolander.sprinkles.Transaction.finish(Transaction.java:58)
>                                                                            at se.emilsjolander.sprinkles.Model.save(Model.java:81)

Why is this happening?

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463767/failed-to-find-provider-info-for-custom-provider) question, might be useful

Answer (score -1):

> **Content change notifications**
>   Android 8.0 (API level 26) changes how ContentResolver.notifyChange()
>   and registerContentObserver(Uri,
>   boolean, ContentObserver) behave for apps targeting Android 8.0.
>
> These APIs now require that a valid ContentProvider is defined for the
>   authority in all Uris. Defining a valid ContentProvider with relevant
>   permissions will help defend your app against content changes from
>   malicious apps, and prevent you from leaking potentially private data
>   to malicious apps.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html#ccn